# jquery-ui autocomplete asp.net mvc does not run

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a form on my mv5 website where users can write reviews of restaurants. In the form there is a restaurant name field. I have added jquery-ui autocomplete to the field so the user can search for restaurants on the website database. However when I type in the restaurant name field. The autocomplete doesn't run.

Any help would be appreciated.

Review cshtml file

```
@model BiteWebsite.Models.CompoundReviewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Review</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RestaurantName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("RestaurantName", null, new { id = "RestaurantSearch" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Food, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Food)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Food)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ambience, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ambience)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ambience)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Service)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RestaurantName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("RestaurantName", null, new { id = "RestaurantSearch" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>

</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#RestaurantSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetRestaurant")'

        });
    });
</script>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

}
```

Review Controller

```
// GET: /Review/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Review/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CompoundReviewModel Model)
        {
            var review = new Review()
            {
                Title = Model.Title,
                Description = Model.Description,
                Food = Model.Food,
                Ambience = Model.Ambience,
                Service = Model.Service,
                Value = Model.Value
            };
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Reviews.Add(review);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(review);
        }

        public JsonResult GetRestaurant(string term)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            List<string> Restaurant;
            Restaurant = db.Restaurants.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(term)).Select(y => y.Name).ToList();
            return Json(Restaurant, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

CompoundReviewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BiteWebsite.Models
{
    public class CompoundReviewModel
    {
        public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
        public Review Review { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Food")]
        public int Food { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ambience")]
        public int Ambience { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Service")]
        public int Service { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Value")]
        public int Value { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Restaurant Name")]
        public string RestaurantName { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, two things.

1. A reference to jQuery
2. A reference to the jquery ui css.

Adding both of these allowed the code to work as is for me, all be it with dummy data on the controller side.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#RestaurantSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetRestaurant")'

        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: Screen grab]

Comment: I have added the references to jquery and jquery ui css but it still isn't working. Could there be a problem with my GetRestaurant function in the controller?

Comment: It all looks fine to me, try it with the dummy one I created instead. It might narrow it down a bit. Here is the code: var restsObj = new List<Restaurant>();
   restsObj.Add(new Restaurant { Name = "a" });
   restsObj.Add(new Restaurant { Name = "b" });
   List<string> rests = restsObj.Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(term)).Select(y => y.Name).ToList();
   return Json(rests, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Can you check the response coming from your controller too?
It's not behind an authenticated controller or anything is it?

Comment: I solved the issue I was using a different version of j query so chnaged  `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` to `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. Thanks

Comment: Nice one. Good luck with the rest. :)